Mixin warning after updating to sass 1.77.8
After updating Sass to version 1.77.8 I get a lot of warnings in the entire project.

"Sass's behavior for declarations that appear after nested rules will
be changing to match the behavior specified by CSS in an upcoming
version. To keep the existing behavior, move the declaration above the
nested rule. To opt into the new behavior, wrap the declaration in & {}."

I understand that it mostly relates to code like this:
.infoItem {
    &:not(:last-child) {
      margin-bottom: 32px;
    }

    max-width: 190px;

    @include Breakpoints.smallerThan('md') {
      max-width: none;
      margin: 0 15px 32px 0;
    }
 }

needing to be updated to code like this:
.infoItem {
    &:not(:last-child) {
      margin-bottom: 32px;
    }

    & {
      max-width: 190px;
    }

    @include Breakpoints.smallerThan('md') {
      max-width: none;
      margin: 0 15px 32px 0;
    }
}

Which I find is a very time-consuming task to do in the entire project. I have read some posts of people struggling with the same, where other people recommend not updating the version to avoid the problem. I don't really think that will be a solution for this project, as it says that this will be breaking changes in future versions. I have also read that people say you can reorder the lines instead of wrapping in &{}, but this will be just as time consuming.
I also get the same warning on lines like this:
@mixin h2-spacing() {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;

}
What am I supposed to do here? wrap margin-top and margin-bottom in &{} as well? if that is the case, then why?
